# error using double genericity

Tags: c#, generics

I have this classes and interface:

```
public class BasicListViewModel<T> : ObservableObject , IListViewOperations<T>,IUpdateHandler
        where T : bre.Domein.Entity

public interface IListViewOperations<T> where T:bre.Domein.Entity

public class IngredientInVoorraad : bre.Domein.Entity
```

the compiler gives the following error for this code:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'bre.Presentatie.BasicListViewModel' to 'bre.Presentatie.IListViewOperations

```
 var viewModelsPages = new List<IListViewOperations<Entity>>();
     var allIngredientsViewModel = new BasicListViewModel<IngredientInVoorraad>(()=>RepositoryFactory.getIngredientInVoorraadRepository().FindAll());
     viewModelsPages.Add(allIngredientsViewModel);  //COMPILE ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

I dont't get why this doesn't work: BasisListViewModel inherits from IListViewOperations and IngredientInVoorraad Inherits from Entity.

Can anyone explain why this is wrong and how to fix it while keeping the interface and genericity?

thanks for helping me!

Comment: It's not because `BasicListViewModel<IngredientInVoorraad>` is a  `IListViewOperations<Entity>` that `List<BasicListViewModel<IngredientInVoorraad>>` is a  `List<IListViewOperations<Entity>>`. Look up covariance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface IListViewOperations is not covariant. If you set your interface definition to `IListViewOperations<out T>`, your interface would become covariant and such conversions would become implicit. Read further on covariance and contravariance in the following MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's not because `BasicListViewModel<IngredientInVoorraad>` is a  `IListViewOperations<Entity>` that `List<BasicListViewModel<IngredientInVoorraad>>` is a  `List<IListViewOperations<Entity>>`. Think about it, it would mean that you could `Add` any `IListViewOperations<Entity>`to the list, not just a `BasicListViewModel<IngredientInVoorraad>`.

Look up covariance. Covariance is supported in C#, but only for interfaces. For example, an `IEnumerable<BasicListViewModel<IngredientInVoorraad>` is a `IEnumerable<IListViewOperations<Entity>`.

For more information, see [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)